# Rename file after upload and saved

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, rename

I have build a nice uploading system to `upload` file and save it on the server where the user can also upload multiple files at once.
The files are saved to different directories depending upon where the user wants to save them. There is also an access database with users and the file name they upload, so every user has his own list of files. I did it so that the user can delete only his files and download all the others.

Now the user wants to be able to change the file name after it has been uploaded.
I have no idea how to do it, the question is if that is even possible?
Can I add a `button` so that when the user clicks on it I shows a `textbox` where the user can enter the new name and after that he clicks `save` and the file name changes on the file itself and on the `access` table?

Can it be done with AJAX when I send the old name and the new name?

I working on asp.net and C#
I hope I explain myself.

Comment: Can you show us some code? I'm not sure how you are currently displaying the list of files

Comment: @CodingKiwi, what code do you want I show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it either with asp.net page or web service.
Create a new asp.net page, add there code to rename file

```
System.IO.File.Move(@"some\path\file1.jpg", @"some\path\file2.jpg");
System.IO.File.Delete(@"some\path\file1.jpg");
...
<write here code to update access database>
```

Call that page from ajax.

Comment: thanks so what I am doing is too "fool" the user, I do not really rename the file, I making new one with new name and delete the old one, how do I check if the file is not on use? I know I can not work on open files

Comment: I tried what you wrote and it work, I did not use the System.IO.File.Delete(@"some\path\file1.jpg"); I saw that the file renamed and not been copied.

Comment: @hanan-mstudio Nice to hear, it worked. Ya i see Delete statement is not required.

Comment: How I close this as answered ?

Comment: @hanan-mstudio you already did it by ticking the green right mark just left to this answer.

Comment: Thanks, it is close but I can add comment, I thought that close is complete close

Answer (score 0):

For sure it is possible, you have a function "System.IO.File.Rename(string oldName, string newName)" - check it, I may not remember it exactly. You can do it with AJAX without any issue at all. Just be sure you have write permission to the file (you should already have that if you just uploaded that file).